# Python 3 struct.pack(): char format requires a bytes object of length 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I'm trying to send push notifications using the APNS from Python (I know there are lots of libraries that do just that, but this has pedagogic intentions).

I started using this script ([source](http://nthn.me/posts/2012/push.html)):

```
def send_push(token, payload):
    # Your certificate file
    cert = 'ck.pem'

    # APNS development server
    apns_address = ('gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195)

    # Use a socket to connect to APNS over SSL
    s = socket.socket()
    sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3, certfile=cert)
    sock.connect(apns_address)

    # Generate a notification packet
    token = binascii.unhexlify(token)
    fmt = '!cH32sH{0:d}s'.format(len(payload))
    cmd = '\x00'
    message = struct.pack(fmt, cmd, len(token), token, len(payload), payload)
    sock.write(message)
    sock.close()
```

Which works, but Python 2.x only supports TSL until version 1. So I tried to run it using Python 3, and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "push_notificator.py", line 52, in <module>
    send_notification(TOKEN, json.dumps(TEST_PAYLOAD))
  File "push_notificator.py", line 46, in send_push
    payload
struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1
```

So it seems I must convert the payload to binary, but I'm really lost. This is the first time that I work with binary data on Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@cdonts's answer ultimately helped me out, but i thought it might be cleaner in a separate answer, instead of a comment...

@cdonts's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551978/2298002

I had to encode both `cmd` as well as `payload`, before packing.
here is my code that solved it...

```
cmd = bytes(cmd, "utf-8")
payload = bytes(payload, "utf-8")
```

here is a longer code snippet to demonstrate in context...

```
token = "<string apns token from iOS client side>"
try:
    token = binascii.unhexlify(token)
    payload = json.dumps(payload)
    fmt = "!cH32sH{0:d}s".format(len(payload))
    cmd = '\x00'

    #python3 requirement
    cmd = bytes(cmd, "utf-8")
    payload = bytes(payload, "utf-8")

    msg = struct.pack(fmt, cmd, len(token), token, len(payload), payload)
except Exception as e: # ref:
    print(e)
```

@cdonts THANK YOU!! (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551978/2298002)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.x use:

```
bytes(payload, "utf-8")
```

Replace `utf-8` with the necessary encoding.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cdonts. Unfortunately it doesn't work, I get the same error: `struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1`.

Comment: @Tae Maybe the object length is greater than 1 or the problem is with `token` instead of `payload`.

Comment: If that were the case then the error would occur running the code under Python 2 too. Finally I tried another format: `!BH32sH%ds`, but I'm still puzzled about why the other one works with Python 2 but not with Python 3. As far as I know the syntax is the same.

Comment: what is the fully executable code? Could you paste that out? Thanks!

Comment: @cdonts's answer helped solved my problem (with an additional step), and without having to change formats, thank you! i posted a new answer that provides more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61992926/2298002